# Understanding call() with multiple variables

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling to learn something beyond the absolute basics of javascript here.  I've been following along with a tutorial and am doing great with the basics they are presenting but I'm trying to step it up and not having much luck.  I'm using a game called Hackmud as a tool for learning/developing some skill with JS.  Here is what I have and what I'm attempting...

Basically, I'm running a command in a terminal type window, parsing the output and then executing another command based upon those results.

```
function (context, args) {

function stringFormat(stringToFormat) {

    return stringToFormat.split('\n').join(' ')
}

function search(regex, response) {
        let matches = regex.exec(response)
        //let match2 = regex.exec(response)
        let arr = []

        while (matches) {
            if (matches.index === regex.lastIndex) {
                regex.lastIndex++
            }
        // Replace eliminates trailing , or . punctuation
         arr.push(matches[1].replace(/([.,])+$/, "") || matches[2])
         matches = regex.exec(response)
     }
    // return arr
    return [...new Set(arr)]
}

let page = {}

let response = stringFormat(args.target.call())
let sitePages = search(/\s(\w+)\s\|/g, response)

response = stringFormat(args.target.call({}))
let siteNav = search(/\s(\w+)\:"(\w+)/g, response)
let siteKey = search(/\s\w+:"(\w+)/g, response)
// let wallPat = /\s(\w+)\:"(\w+)/g
// let siteNav = wallPat.exec(response)

// Captures password for site 
 page[siteNav] = sitePages[1]
 response = args.target.call(page)
 let sitePass = search(/(?:strategy\s)(\S+)/g, response)

page[siteNav] = sitePages[0]
response = args.target.call(page)

// Regex captures project names from "of projects, ment on, and nues on" for developments and continues
// Need to eliminte trailing punctuation if there.
let siteProjects = search(/(?:of\sproject\s|ments\son\s|nues\son\s)(\S+)/g, response)

// return args.target.call(page)
return [["`NTarget:`", siteKey], ["`NPasswd:`", sitePages[1]], ["`NProjects:`", siteProjects], ["`NPasswd:`", sitePass]]
}
```

This is basically returning me a bunch of details that I'm trying to use to get to the next step in the process of the game.  The problem is that the next step would involve passing into the args.target.call() several of the key:value pairs that I'm harvesting.  This is where I'm stumped.  I've been researching but I think I'm missing some key concept that is preventing me from finding what I need.

In game context, a command that this is operating on looks like:

```
>>tyrell.public { get:"description" }
Want something new and original?  Go somewªere else!  Taco Tyrell's has been replicating Tyrell's Perfect Taco down to the molecul¦ for sixty years. Try it! You'll Like It Exactly As Much As You Did The First Time.(tm)
We are calling this strategy bethebest and we will continue to strive to deliver on this promise.
```

The next step involves executing a command something like:

```
>>tyrell.public { get:"list", p:"bethebest", project:"forgetme_nt" }
```

I'm really lost here on how to pass into the call() these multiple key:value pairs.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that depends on the function implementation.

The arguments themselves can be parsed as JSON, but calling a method does not really work via key/value pairs, but only via positional arguments. So you cannot assign `get` to the argument called `get`, because that information (to my knowledge) is not stored anywhere.

If you implement this function, you could just accept a generic `options` argument, that contains a plain object, just as it was entered in the command prompt. Then your function can iterate over the object keys or do whatever with it.